# IPython Notebook interprets empty lines from save_script output

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I use the save_script = True option in the IPython Notebook config file to save a script file of my notebooks. One of these script (.py) files I add to my /Python27/ArcGISXX/Lib/ directory and then I have recently ran into a problem where 
I've found that with the most recent version of IPython, that when I use save_script = True, IPython interprets the .py file with blank lines added between each line.  So I try to import this .py file like a package and it has syntax errors because it interprets blank lines between every line.  Is this happening to anyone else?  How can I address it?

I am running Windows 7 and have IPython installed with the "Background Geoprocessing (64-bit)" installation of Python 2.7 for ArcMap.

Comment: What version of IPython are you on? We just released 2.3.1 fixing a similar problem to the one you describe, so try updating to that.

Comment: You guys are on it. I was on 2.3.0 and the update to 2.3.1 fixed me up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

This was a bug in IPython 2.3.0; we released the fix as 2.3.1.

For those who want the details, here's [the bug report](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6599) and [the pull request](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/6911) that fixed it.